# "Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally"

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, java-8, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run a simple selenium case on Ubuntu 16.4 to check my updated ChromeDriver version. Here is my settings information:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Chromium: 69.0.3497.81, Built on Ubuntu , 
Chromedriver: v2.8.240825
jdk: openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
```

And here is my simple java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "/tmp/chromedriver.log");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");

        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless", "window-size=1024,768", "--no-sandbox");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        System.out.println("Title is " + driver.getTitle());

        if (driver.getPageSource().contains("I'm Feeling Lucky")) {
            System.out.println("Pass");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fail");
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
```

But during the runtime, I'm keep getting **"Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally"**, with such in the log file:

```
 "
....
    [0.317][INFO]: Launching chrome: /usr/bin/chromium-browser --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --dis
    able-web-resources --enable-logging --full-memory-crash-report --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.GO6lAd/internal --logging-level=1 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --re
    mote-debugging-port=12811 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.uTbJHO data:,
    [0.317][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12811/json/version
    [0.319][WARNING]: PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
    [0.390][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
    [0.440][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12811/json/version
    [0.441][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
    "
```

But if I was to downgradethe the ChromeDriver to version 2.4, same code runs perfectly. Does anyone know why ? The reason why I need the latest one, is because there is some other feature I need to use.

Comment: try adding --disable-gpu argument

Comment: Sorry, I just realized ChromeDriver 2.42 was actually the latest one, I was confused about these version numbers.  So in that case, please ignore my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The failure was actually with older Chrome-driver, of version 2.9, 2.8. etc. The very latest ones, 2.38, or 2.42 does not have such behavior.